# Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с функцией js массивы(В цикле for использовались методы includes и push.)

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции, push

Помогите пожалуйста (только начал изучать `js`), мне нужно написать функцию, которая получает два массива произвольной длины в параметры `array1` и `array2`, и возвращает новый массив, состоящий из тех элементов, которые присутствуют в обоих исходных массивах. В цикле for использовались методы `includes` и `push`.

```js
const array1 = [1, 2, 5, 3];
const array2 = [1, 2, 7, 3, 8];

function getElements(array1, array2) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) { //проходимся по первому массиву
    let newArray = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) { // по второму
      const arr1 = array1[i];
      const arr2 = array2[j];
      if (arr1 === arr2) { //if (array1[i].includes(array2[j]))  //проверяем на совпадение через includes (но у меня не работает)
        newArray = array1.push(array2); //возвращаю новый массив, состоящий из тех элементов, которые присутствуют в обоих исходных массивах. (не работает)
      }
    }
    return newArray;
  }
```

Что делаю не так - вообще не понимаю((((

Comment: @Dmitry Ещё одну скобку пожалуйста добавьте в конец ф-ии :)

Comment: @EzioMercer я стараюсь не лезть в код, написанный ТС'ом, поскольку зачастую в этом может скрываться ошибка, в том числе и опечатки. Вот так написано у автора, ок. Накалывались, знаем))

Comment: @Dmitry Понял вас, логично! Но на английском SO мне сказали, если ошибки в опечатках, то такие вопросы надо просто исправлять и закрывать. Думал тут так же)

Comment: @EzioMercer это для тех, кто разбирается в языке. Javascript не импонирует мне, поэтому если проблема вопроса действительно решается исправлением опечатки в коде, то его закроют, те кто понимает. Без форматирования кода, который я сделал, большинство даже смотреть не будет

Comment: Нужен массив, состоящий из тех элементов, которые присутствуют в обоих исходных массивах

Comment: `newArray = array1.push(array2);` - посмотри что возвращает метод [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Comment: Метод push() добавляет один или несколько элементов в конец массива

Comment: @МаксимНовичокjs, и что он возвращает?

Comment: const array1 = [1, 2, 5, 3];
const array2 = [1, 2, 7, 3, 8]; с этих двух - 5

Comment: До этого делал практику, все понятно: Дополни код функции createArrayOfNumbers(min, max) так, чтобы она возвращала массив всех целых чисел от значения min до max.  Мой код:                    
       `function createArrayOfNumbers(min, max) {
        const numbers = [];
        for(let i = min;  i <= max; i++)
        numbers.push(i);
        return numbers;
        }`     С этим заданием завис...

Comment: @Dmitry Понял вашу позицию, спасибо за разъяснение)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправленный вариант:

```
const intersection = (array1, array2) => {
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    if (array2.includes(array1[i])) {
      result.push(array1[i]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Более короткое и удобное решение:

```
const intersection = array1.filter(x => array2.includes(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

Метод [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) возвращает количество элементов в массиве, после добавления.

Таким образом в строке

```
newArray = array1.push(array2);
```

переменной `newArray` присваивается число.

Вместо этого, нужно было добавлять найденный элемент в сам массив `newArray`

```
newArray.push(arr1)
```

а также необходимо вынести объявление `newArray` из первого цикла, точно также как и `return`.

---

Для случая с [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes): внутренний цикл вообще не нужен.

Нужен только `if`, в котором *значение элемента* будет проверяться *во втором массиве*

```
if (array2.includes(array1[i])) {
    // добавляем элемент в newArray
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать делать

Answer (score 0):

Оставлю этот ответ как ненавистник `array.includes` внутри цикла:

```js
const nums1 = [1, 2, 5, 3];
const nums2 = [1, 2, 7, 3, 8];

const findIntersection = (array1, array2) => {
  const array1Set = new Set(array1);
  const intersection = [];
  
  for (const num of array2) {
    if (array1Set.has(num)) {
      intersection.push(num);
    }
  }
  
  return intersection;
}

console.log(findIntersection(nums1, nums2));
```

Так сложность алгоритма снижается с `O(n * m)` до `O(n + m)`, где `n` и `m` - это длины массивов соответсвнно

Answer (score 0):

let array = [];
const intersection = (num1, num2)

```
for (i = 0; i < num1.length; i += 1){
   num2.includes(num1[i])
  ?(array.push(num1[i]))
  : false;

}
```